# conditional doing both the if and else statement

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a page were you need a button to be either enabled or disabled based on the quantity of the item. So I did an if-statement:

```
<?php
{

 global $woocommerce;   
 $targeted_id = 523;


 foreach ( WC()-&gt;cart-&gt;get_cart() as $cart_item ) 
 { 
  if($cart_item['product_id'] == $targeted_id )
  {
    $qty =  $cart_item['quantity'];
    break;
    }         

   }

  if ( $qty &gt; 0 )
  {  

    ?> <button 
    onclick="location.href='http://noespecadotiendagourmet.com/paso-3/'" 
    type="button">
    PASO SIGUIENTE</button> <?php


    }
   else
   {

    ?> <button 
    onclick="location.href='http://noespecadotiendagourmet.com/paso-3/'" 
    type="button" disabled> PASO SIGUIENTE</button> <?php         

    }




   ?>
```

But for some reason two buttons are created with this:

[image]

EDIT:
just  checked the source and for some reason everything except the buttons themselves are commented, i dont understand why

[image]

Comment: Are there 2 items in the cart? One of them prints the first button, the other prints the second button?

Comment: There are too many `&gt;`'s. Are those bad pastes or were generated from somewhere?

Comment: two items in the cart would make `$qty` equal 2 @DirkScholten

Comment: doesnt matter if there is one or none, and i have setted up so it only can be 1 item either way it always shows 2 buttons

Comment: I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @NigelRen About your edit https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51897396/3 - you went and fixed what we don't know if their syntax was in fact what they have/used. Edit: Ok, you re-edited now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've put it back as I was approving another edit and assumed it was just a typo.

Comment: @NigelRen alrighty :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah now i know why it didnt work, sorry for the newbie question everybody

Ended up using PHP code snippets (Insert PHP) plugin to write the code to do it

```
global $woocommerce;    
$targeted_id = an id;
$qty = 0;



foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) 
{ 
if($cart_item['product_id'] == $targeted_id )
{
    $qty =  $cart_item['quantity'];
    break;
    }         

}

if ( $qty == 0 )
{  
 ?> 

     <form action="asite.com/" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="next" 
     name="Submit" id="next" disabled/>
     </form>
     <?php  

}
else
{
 ?>   
      <form action="asite.com/" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="next" 
     name="Submit" id="next" />
     </form> 
     <?php

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `&gt;` is not a valid PHP comparison operator: `if ( $qty > 0 )` is what you should use.

Honestly there are a couple of other `&gt;`'s in this code which should throw syntax errors as well.

Comment: Exactly @splash58, it would throw a syntax error on the semi-colon. Honestly some of the OP's other code appears to use this.

Comment: i doing the php part inside of a page and if i use plain > it thinks i am closing the php sentence

Comment: That makes no sense @leonidas56

Comment: @leonidas56 Only when viewing HTML source will the `&gt;`'s be shown as `>`.

Comment: if i just use plain < and > it ends up showing something like this https://imgur.com/FvDBIIZ

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. Are you mixing HTML and PHP?

Comment: You need to show us how. Edit your code in your original post.

Comment: thats all there is, i am inside a wordpress product and i am using <?php ?> to write code in php to validate the amount if items in the cart and then create the button either enabled or disabled, sorry i am pretty new with php so i may be doing something really wrong

Comment: @JayBlanchard just to test it again i did change it to if ( $qty < 0 ) it doesnt break it like changing the other &lt; but it stills has two buttons